# Should UI elements all use the theme color?

Tags: color, interface-design, design-principles

In the image below,the buttons at the bottom are used to skip forward/backward exactly one frame each tap. The slider lets the user scrub through the video in a "faster" way.

**From a UI perspective - should the buttons be in the theme color, which is also used for the 'Next'. Or should they be white? What is your recommendation and why?**

[[image]

*Click the image for a full version.*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQaWI.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To express my opinion, they are fine the way you have them.

Colour in UI should not be decorative as much as it should be functional and informative. If you keep using that colour in all elements that are interactive, like play, pause, next, previous, send...etc you are doing it right. The colour informs the user that "Next Frame" is an interactive object and will perform an action and in this case the white text is just for reading.

This would go wrong if you use purple in all "clickable" objects and then also on some texts or titles that are not for the user to click.

Does this make sense?

Comment: I'm with Joana here. UX/UI principles would suggest that you're going to increase ease of use by being consistent (not decorative). So as long as it matches the rest of your app(?) in terms of usage of purple objects, you're all good. If that's not the case, you'll want to make a change but that change would need to be carried out across the board. If you want help with this, feel free to post more questions or comment back :)

Comment: Thank you both @AshleePalka . I just needed this confirmation that i'm on the right path (i'm not a designer haha). The rest of the app is with the same principles . Thank you! :)